# Windows 10 - Unable to change domain password when password has expired and computer is locked

Tags: windows-10

We have recently migrated over to Windows 10 Pro Version 1511. Prior to that we were on Windows 7 Pro.

We have fast user switching disabled for all computers by group policy in our domain. It is quite common that users don't change their password even though they are given password expiration notice.

On Windows 7 clients when a domain users account password had expired after they had logged in and the computer gets locked (for lunch or they were idle) they came back to login and they were able to change the password as they had a switch user option as shown below.

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/ad2745ee41.jpg))</sub>

However, in Windows 10 when the same situation happens we get the following prompt:

"Your password has expired. To set a new password, select OK, select Switch user, re-enter your current password, then follow the prompts on the screen.

So we click ok and now there is no longer a switch user option?

[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/ad2bbbc78e.jpg))</sub>

Has anyone come across this yet? Wonder if this is a bug in Windows 10 or a limitation of some kind?

Comment: Is there an "Other user" option from the login screen (bottom left-hand)?  Is there a reason someone cannot just reset the AD password for the user (on a DC) requiring a change on login?

Comment: No "other user" on the bottom left hand side I'm afraid. Yes that could be done but I'd consider that a workaround and am looking for a fix so end users can change their own password.

Answer (score 1):

The switch user option is likely disabled in your environment, for security reasons.

1. Have the customer log onto another computer.
2. Let whoever does account management in your organization do their
   job and reset the user's password.  It is not a workaround, it the
   simplest solution.
3. Also, the customer probably will not be able to unlock their session,
   and will probably have to restart the computer anyway, so that's
   another way.

As for allowing customers to change their own passwords, they already can.  However, you need to ensure that they get ample warning of account expiration.  If they have to click past a warning for two weeks to get into their account, they have no one to blame but themselves for the inconvenience of contacting the service desk to get a password reset.

Comment: Hello Xalorous.

While you raise many valid points and this isn't the biggest deal in the world as it will only occur under certain circumstances.

As I explained in the post we have fast user switching disabled - this is intentional and has always been set in our domain. What I'm saying is that in Windows 10 the behaviour has changed and wanted to know if this was a new limitation or a bug...

Comment: @AshleyH I have not tested this on Windows 7 Enterprise, though I think I recall this happening there.  Our folks are still developing our Win 10 for deployment so I can't test it here to duplicate what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to windows update from August which disables falling back to NTLM from Kerberos https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms16-101.aspx